# Почему template не выводит данные?

Tags: python, django, django-template

Пробую сделать сайт, выводящий погоду. Все данные спокойно передаются в context, да и все успешно сохраняется в дб. Но вот на выводе получается, что просто пару пустых колонок, которые ничего не выводят. С чем это может быть связано?

```py
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm

def index(request):
    appid='8daaf5ff8c413765ce21a9610fad80cf'  #https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys
    url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=' + appid

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    all_cities =[]

    for city in cities:
        res = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json()
        city_info = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temp': res['main']['temp'],
            'icon': res['weather'][0]['icon'],
            }
        print(city_info)
        if res.get('main'):
            city_info = {
                'city': city.name,
                'temp': res['main']['temp'],
                'icon': res['weather'][0]['icon'],
                'error': False,
            }
        else:
            city_info= {
                'city': city.name,
                'error': True
            }
        all_cities.append(city_info)

    context = {'all_info': city_info, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'weather/weather.html', context)
```

Templates:

```html
</div>
<div class="col-5 offset-2">
  <h1>Information</h1>


  {% for info in all_info %}
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9">
        <b>City:</b> {{ info.city }} <br>
        <b>Temperature:</b> {{ info.temp }}<sup>o</sup> <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 offset-1">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{ info.icon }}.png" alt="photo weather">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image: Вывод в браузере]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы скорее всего не верно передаете данные в `context`. Переменная `city_info` не содержит то, что вы ожидаете в template.
Моя догадка, что вы используете переменную `all_cities`, в которую помещаете данные обо всех городах, но при этом в контексте ее нет.
Попробуйте так

```py
    context = {'all_info': all_cities, 'form': form}
```

Переменная `all_cities` содержит список всех городов со значениями, которые вы перебрали в `for`-директиве. Передав ее в `template` вы можете забрать данные

Для отладки используйте `print(context)` перед `return`, чтобы увидеть данные, которые предаются на страницу